How can you specify python runtime version in vercel?
I am trying to deploy a simple FastAPI app to vercel for the first time.
Vercel.json is exactly below.
{
  "devCommand": "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "api/index.py",
      "use": "@vercel/python",
      "config": {
        "maxLambdaSize": "15mb",
        "runtime": "python3.9"
      }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/index.py"
    }
  ]
}

I have specified runtime as python3.9, but this doesn't reflect actual runtime which is still python3.12 (default).This ends up causing internal error.
How can I configure runtime version correctly?
I also read the official docs which says builds property shouldn't be used. So I tried to rewrite like below.
{
  "devCommand": "uvicorn main:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port 3000",
  "functions": {
    "api/index.py":
    {
      "runtime": "python@3.9"
    }
  },
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "api/index.py"
    }
  ]
}

This didn't work as well.
Maybe I shouldn't use vercel for python project?(little information in the internet)

I've scrolled through vercel docs but wasn't been able find any references that python version could be specified in builds or functions section of Vercel.json.

in 'builds' you specify npm package @vercel/python. I guess this is more like interface for node.js to run python3 scripts.
in 'functions' you kind off specify serverless functions. I'm not sure that this is what you need.

Ref: https://vercel.com/docs/projects/project-configuration
Solution:
However as it is listed in Vercel documentation python version could be defined in the Pipfile.
Ref: https://vercel.com/docs/functions/runtimes/python
Note Vercel only supports python 3.12 (default) and python 3.9 (requires legacy image i.e. use Node.js 16 or 18.)
Vercel Manuals:
This links might be useful for setting up your first python project on vercel:
https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python/hello-world
https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python/flask3
https://github.com/vercel/examples/tree/main/python
What worked for me
First create your http handler or flask app or else:
## my_app.py
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import sys

class GETHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
 
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header('Content-type','text/plain')
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write('Hello, world!\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        python_version = f"{sys.version_info[0]}.{sys.version_info[1]}.{sys.version_info[2]}"
        self.wfile.write(f'Python version {python_version}'.encode('utf-8'))

# variable required by Vercel
handler = GETHandler

Next create a Pipfile. This bash commands will automatically create a Pipfile.
## run in bash
pip install pipenv
pipenv install

Automatically generated pipfile should look smth like this:
## Pipfile
[[source]]
url = "https://pypi.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true
name = "pypi"

[packages]
pipenv = "~=2023.12"

[dev-packages]

[requires]
python_version = "3.9"

Next create package.json. You need to set node.js version to 18.x for running your scripts in python 3.9.
## package.json
{
    "engines": {
      "node": "18.x"
    }
    
}

Third, you need to define routes that will trigger executing python server:
## vercel.json
{
"builds": [
    { "src": "*.py", "use": "@vercel/python" }
  ],
  "redirects": [
    { "source": "/", "destination": "/my_app.py" }
  ]  

}

Finally let's set up Deployment Settings. In my project settings I don't add any run or build commands:

However for python 3.9 check that your node.js version is 18.x (same page, i.e. in the Deployment Settings).

That's it. After the deployment visit the generated route link and it will automatically redirect you to /my_app.py. You can see that python 3.9 was used to generate the page:


Thank you for your solution!
Pipfile didn't work for me unfortunately.

@agongji I was able to set up Python3.9 env on my vercel account. Thus updated my answer: 1. added links to several useful examples from vercel git; 2. step-by-step guide that worked on my computer.

Thank you for the step-by-step guide! It also worked to me!
